# Observe for ItemChanged on two ReactiveLists

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel in which I would like to listen for changes to items in two ReactiveLists, Payments and AccountPayments. The Lists are instantiated and the ChangeTrackingEnabled is set to true:

```
this.Payments = new ReactiveList<transaction.PaymentViewModel>();
this.Payments.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;`
this.AccountPayments = new ReactiveList<AccountPaymentViewModel>();
this.AccountPayments.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;`
```

Then, defined in my ViewModel, I have an ObservableAsPropertyHelper readonly property:

```
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<decimal> _totalPayments;
public decimal TotalPayments { get { return _totalPayments.Value; } }
```

My intent is to set TotalPayments whenever any of these items change in both lists. I tried using WhenAny:

```
this.WhenAny(vm => vm.Payments.ItemChanged,
            vm => vm.AccountPayments.ItemChanged,
            (a, b) => a.Sender.Payments
                .Where(x => x.Amount.HasValue).Sum(x => x.Amount.Value)
                + b.Sender.AccountPayments
                .Where(x => x.Amount.HasValue).Sum(x => x.Amount.Value))
            .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.TotalPayments, out _totalPayments);
```

While this compiles fine, it doesn't seem to catch the changes.
I also tried using WhenAnyObservable:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(
            vm => vm.Payments.ItemChanged,
            vm => vm.AccountPayments.ItemChanged)
            .Select(_ =>
                this.Payments.Where(x => x.Amount.HasValue)
                    .Sum(x => x.Amount.Value)
                + this.AccountPayments.Where(x => x.Amount.HasValue)
                    .Sum(x => x.Amount.Value))
            .ToProperty(this, vm => vm.TotalPayments, out _totalPayments);
```

But this won't compile.
Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first won't work as it's observing property changes and `ItemChanged` itself won't change, it's an observable.

The second is pretty much correct, but requires a bit of a modification. `WhenAnyObservable` requires that all the observables are the same type.  As you're uninterested in the actual result, you can select `Unit` and merge the two:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(a => a.Payments.ItemChanged).Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .Merge(this.WhenAnyObservable(a => a.AccountPayments.ItemChanged).Select(_ => Unit.Default));
```

You can't select `Unit.Default` within `WhenAnyObservable` as it re-writes this expression to observe the property changes to make sure it has the latest observable.  If neither `Payments` nor `AccountPayments` will change (i.e. they're read only), you can omit the `WhenAnyObservable` altogether:

```
Payments.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    .Merge(AccountPayments.ItemChanged.Select(_ => Unit.Default));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Charles. I was in fact missing the closing paren (how embarrassing), however, the compilation error persisted. Having found that my second snippet was the correct method, I dug a little deeper. It turns out that the issue was something that I didn't mention in my question. The two lists contain two different Types. The AccountPayment is a different class than the Payment class. Kind of silly of me. Again, thanks for your code review and pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @StuartMiller ... that's what my answer says.  Though I'll confess I did miss it when I answered initially, perhaps you hadn't seen the edit!

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen your edit. That's exactly what I needed, and I didn't know that. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Just test this and ran into another issue. I'm getting a runtime exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' saying "Index expressions are only supported with constants". Seems to happen when I try to return Unit.Default.

Comment: @StuartMiller ah, you're right.  `WhenAny` sets up a property changed listener to track changes to the expression within, so doing anything fancy isn't supported.  I'll update.

Comment: Charles, your code works beautifully. Thanks so much for all your help! I've corrected my original post to include the missing closing paren at the end of my Select.